# Find records that doesn't have associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, `Post` has_many `Comments`.

How to find all posts that doesn't have any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a not exists like:

```
Post.where(" not exists (select 'x' from comments where comments.post_id = posts.id)")
```

Comment: I'd use a counter cache to avoid the sub query. If you have a lot of comments, this could be unnecessarily slow.

Answer (score 3):

For better performance, use a counter_cache column:

`belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true`

[api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#counter_cache), 
[Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)

Then you can do:

`Post.where("comments_count = ?", 0)`